# Что лучше использовать для конвертации текста в форматы mobi, epub и т.д.?

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск-библиотек, rss

Стоит задача конвертации rss новостной ленты в форматы типа .mobi, .epub, .pdf и другие. Хочется написать всё красиво. Вопрос - есть ли какой-нибудь удобный модуль, который может с этим помочь?

Answer (score 0):

Есть конвертер в .epub, но нужно будет установить Calibre

https://github.com/lazzarello/rss-epub-archiver